# How does Server Side works?

Tags: extjs, dll, server-side

I am developing an Extjs App and I have to use a DLL on my app. Someone in this forum told me that it is not possible to make it directly with Extjs but that I have to make it works with a Server Side.

I am new at Dlls and also Server Side is a new term for me. Someone may explay me how Server Side works and How can I make it works with a Dll into my Extjs App.

Comment: Server Side is not a product, it means that the code should be run on a server rather than on a client. As an example, a client would be a browser running javascript, and the server (on the server side) could be running java, or php, or some other 'server side' languaje.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the dll, WHat is the dll's use and the purpose.

Extjs is a Web application framework, It is possible to use Windows apps in a web browser, but this generally implies use of a browser plugin. 
For example using a scanner app,  I had to use a Twain web app plugin.